# Adobe Flash Builder Flex Mobile Android: Avoid that user can close the app

Tags: android, apache-flex, flash-builder, termination

I am developing an app for android. It is not always clear to me when the app will be terminated by the OS. Sometimes it happens when you press the back button and sometimes when you press the home button. What is the logic behind this?

My app must be keep activated during a long period (when you run it the app must stay resident). Also another question is if it is possible to popup when an event comes in and activate the screen and bring it to the front.

Does somebody made this already? Or is there more information about this (how to do it). Search the internet but doesn't find some useful things.

Answer (score 1):

Pressing the Back button on the main activity will finish and exit the app.

Pressing the Home button will pause and leave the app in the background, it will return to the previous state when it's restored.

Override the onBackPressed() method on the main activity if you don't want it to quit when the back button is pressed.

If you want an event to occur when the screen is shown, override the onResume() method and do the checks and event required in there.

Comment: Try to find the onResume event but can't find it, do you mean ACTIVATE event? Also checked FlexEvent object but no resume event available. However, i appreciate your explanation, it is not applicable to my question.

Comment: I want to bring it to front myself (from background to front), not reacting on the user app reactivation.

Answer (score 1):

And one more moment - android can close your app when it thinks that it need more memory for more recent apps.

And you may need to use native extensions or even develop your app in java if you want to implement reliable resident behavior.

**Update:** java service+ air ui example:
http://www.jamesward.com/2011/05/11/extending-air-for-android/
**end of update**

And you must know that air apps eat at least 30mb of memory(if they are empty and do nothing), normally they will start from 50-70mb. I guess that no user will wish to allow another 70mb of his memory-hungry device to be eaten by something not critical.

And for automatic maximizing of your window you may need root access.

Comment: Sounds plausible to me but.... Why can other apps like a server app like voxer and airdroid can stay in memory even when they are not in use? Is it because they use some phone services?

Comment: added link to example. in java you can create service app. in air you can use such java app. maybe it is possible to register any app as service through some hack, but now i don't know such ways.

Answer (score 1):

Being that your answer is with Flex the issue is that you need to listen to the stage's keyDown event.

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.Key_DOWN, yourHandler);

Then you need to response to the back button and inhibit this - if your intent is to stop the back button.

```
private function _onStage_keyDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent)
{
    if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.BACK)
    {
        event.stopImmediatePropogation();
        event.preventDefault();
        //your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. You are right but i discover that you must also suppress the view's backKeyPressed event otherwise it will not stop the event.